# How to make copy constructor copy also virtual table?

Tags: c++, inheritance, copy-constructor

Here is simple code snippet. I want to have `I-A-B` class inheritance so that `I`'s copy constructor can also initialize in-place virtual table of derivate class which inherits from `I`.

For simplicity sake we can assume that `sizeof(A) == sizeof(B) == sizeof(I)`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class B;

class I
{
public:
    virtual ~I()
    {
        cout << "~I()\n";
    }

    I()
    {
        cout << "I ctor\n";
    }

    virtual void print()
    {
        cout << "I::print()\n";
    }

    I(const I& clone);

};

class A : public I
{
public:
    ~A() override
    {
        cout << "~A()\n";
    }

    void print() override
    {
        cout << "A::print()\n";
    }
};

class B : public I
{
public:
    B()
    {
        cout << "B ctor\n";
    }

    B(const B& clone)
    {
        cout << "B copy ctor\n";
    }
    
    ~B() override
    {
        cout << "~B()\n";
    }

    void print() override
    {
        cout << "B::print()\n";
    }

};

I::I(const I& clone)
{
    cout << "B copy ctor 2\n";
    B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>((I*)&clone);
    if (b != nullptr)
    {
        this->~I();
        new (this) B(*b);
    }
}


class T
{
public:
    I GetA()
    {
        return B();
    }

};


int main()
{
    cout << "main() ->\n";
    T t;
    {
        cout << "- GetA()\n";
        I i = t.GetA();
        i.print();
        cout << "- before scope end\n";
    }
    cout << "- main scope\n";
    cout << "<- main()\n";
}
```

This produces:

```
main() ->
- GetA()
I ctor
B ctor
B copy ctor 2
~I()
I ctor
B copy ctor
~B()
~I()
I::print()
- before scope end
~I()
- main scope
<- main()
```

But at the end I want to see `~B` being called, not `~I`.

```
main() ->
- GetA()
I ctor
B ctor
B copy ctor 2
~I()
I ctor
B copy ctor
~B()
~I()
B::print()            <--- changed
- before scope end
~B()                  <--- added
~I()
- main scope
<- main()
```

Can anyone propose how this could be solved using standard C++ ?

I would prefer to avoid using `new` memory allocation if possible, but in-place `new` is allowed. Intention is to have less checks for invalid pointers / out of memory, etc problems.

Comment: I think you are saying that you want the `I` you create with `I i = t.GetA();` to have the `B`'s vtable pointer?  `GetA()` returns an `I`.  That returned `I` cannot secretly be a different type.  Returning an `I&` would allow the polymorphism you want.

Comment: This is allowed if you use `I*` instead of `I`. Why this cannot operate on class instance as well - I guess what differentiates the class is it's virtual table, which is stored at first pointer of `this`.

Comment: It's a rule of the language.  Creating a variable of type `I` is a guarantee that the variable has type `I`.  The compiler is allowed to know this and make optimizations based on this.

Comment: The copy constructor must make a copy. Never try to do anything else. For the compiler it is a copy and it can always optimize it using RVO avoiding your definition.

Comment: You might google 'clone idiom', maybe that's what you need.

Comment: Other options to look up would be "type erasure", "variant", "polymorphism with value semantics".

Comment: *"For simplicity sake we can assume that `sizeof(A) == sizeof(B) == sizeof(I)`."* -- This is an invalid simplification. The fact that the sizes could be unequal is a big reason why your plan cannot work. If you work under the assumption that the sizes are the same, you're likely to be blind to the gaping pitfalls you're dancing around.

Comment: @alagner Can you perhaps add your comment as answer here ? Looks interesting indeed.

Comment: @JaMiT I was thinking from starting from simple, and then later on ideate on how to deal with size differences. From my perspective first goal is to abstract API, then figure out containers. But if you can do both, that is even better.

Comment: @PaulSanders could not find it. Can you add your comment as answer with relevant links ?

Comment: I couldn't find much either!  So I added a proper answer, hth

Answer (score 2):

OK, well, the OP has asked about how the `clone idiom` works and a quick google search didn't turn up much, so here's a quick rundown.

Let us assume that:

1. We have a `Base` class with one or more virtual functions (pure or otherwise).
2. One or more classes deriving from `Base`, some or all of which override one or more of these functions.
3. We need to construct a copy of one of these objects when we only have a `Base` pointer available.

Plain old copy constructors don't cut it here, so we need to put some scaffolding in place to provide equivalent functionality.  The usual way to do this is to add  a virtual `clone` function to `Base`, which is often pure virtual (although it doesn't have to be).  So `Base` might then look like this:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base () { }
    virtual std::unique_ptr <Base> clone () = 0;
    virtual const char *whoami () { return "base"; }
//  ...
};
```

We then implement `clone` appropriately in each of the classes inheriting from `Base`.  It is often enough to just call the derived class's copy constructor, for example:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual std::unique_ptr <Base> clone () override { return std::make_unique <Derived> (*this); }
    const char *whoami () override { return "derived"; }
//  ...
}
```

And finally, a little test program:

```
int main ()
{
    Derived d;
    Base *b = &d;
    auto b2 = b->clone ();
    std::cout << b2->whoami ();
}
```

which prints `derived` (yay!).  An additional perk of this approach is that we can pass parameters to `clone` (I myself often find this useful - I sometimes pass in a set of flag bits detailing what to copy).

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eA23XDKF2O3oQeIq)

Comment: This is understandable, but for example for C++ you're dealing with two variables already (b and d). You get more issues after you get out of scope (E.g. b pointer can outlive d instance) or dealing with memory management issues if you want this to be pretty. (pointer ownership, shared_ptr, unique_ptr, weak_ptr, etc...). With C# it's rather simple as C# does not copy classes by default. I've posted my own answer as well. (it's not pretty either).

Comment: @TarmoPikaro This is a bog-standard clone idiom, understood by *virtually* every C++ programmer. Your own code, by contrast, is a mess.

Comment: @TarmoPikaro Look again.  Object lifetime issues are addressed by having `clone` return a `std:: unique_ptr`.  As for C#, it has garbage collection so that problem goes away.

Comment: I think in my case I'm using standard c++. So mess is c++, not my code. (I can use whatever syntax c++ provides). I wanted to avoid call to new originally. New can return null pointer if out of memory, and requires checking that pointer. Checking is expensive as you need to write and maintain that code. Im comparing against C# because it looks prettier than c++ in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Interface `I` cannot be directly used as such - as it's that type on which compiler will operate. In theory it's possible to manually replace vtable into `I* (this)` pointer, but this cannot happen within constructor call, as vtable is properly initialized after successful constructor call. `vtable` replacement will work also with virtual methods, but not with normal class methods.

One approach is to have separate accessor class which would operate on `I*` and direct all operations to `I*`. (In example below called `IC`). This can happen via custom operator `->`.

In order to avoid calls to memory management - like `new` / `delete` and deal with potential out of memory allocation failures and `nullptr` checks - one approach is to use in-place new construction `new (buffer) A|B()` or `new (buffer) A|B(a|b)` - then need to allocate sufficient buffer to accommodate `sizeof(A)` or `sizeof(B)`.

In example below I'm using `static_assert` to produce a compile time error if buffer size is not large enough. Try to add some member field into `A` or `B` to see compilation failure. Allocate larger array e.g. `char lbuf[20];` to fix this. Note that size might be different for debug and release builds.

Example also shows zero copying/constructing/destructing when just cloning base class `IC i2 = i;` - this happens via sharing same pointer by multiple `IC` classes.

Full example here:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class B;

class I
{
public:
    virtual ~I()
    {
        cout << "~I()\n";
    }

    I()
    {
        cout << "I ctor\n";
    }

    virtual void print() = 0;

private:
    I(const I& clone) = delete;
};

class IC    //interface container
{
    // cannot be instantiated on it's own
    IC() = delete;
    // cannot instantiate from existing pointer (this class does not delete pi pointer)
    IC(I* pi) = delete;
public:
    // create new instance
    IC(int i);
    // copy ctor, reuse existing instance
    IC(const IC& ic);
    // create new instance from local copy
    IC(I&& i);

    I* operator->()
    {
        return pI.get();
    }

protected:
    std::shared_ptr<I> wrap(I* pi);
    std::shared_ptr<I> pI;
    char ibuf[sizeof(void*) /*hardcode different value as for max( sizeof(A), sizeof(B) ). For pure no-data classes this should be sufficient */];
};


class A : public I
{
public:
    A()
    {
        cout << "A ctor\n";
    }

    ~A() override
    {
        cout << "~A()\n";
    }

    A(const A& clone)
    {
        cout << "A copy ctor\n";
    }

    void print() override
    {
        cout << "A::print()\n";
    }
};

class B : public I
{
public:
    B()
    {
        cout << "B ctor\n";
    }

    B(const B& clone)
    {
        cout << "B copy ctor\n";
    }
    
    ~B() override
    {
        cout << "~B()\n";
    }

    void print() override
    {
        cout << "B::print()\n";
    }

};

std::shared_ptr<I> IC::wrap(I* pi)
{
    // we only destruct, but don't delete instance
    return shared_ptr<I>(pi, 
        [](I* pi)
        {
            pi->~I();
        }
    );
}


IC::IC(int i)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(ibuf) >= sizeof(A), "increase size of ibuf to hold A's value");
    static_assert(sizeof(ibuf) >= sizeof(B), "increase size of ibuf to hold B's value");
    switch (i)
    {
        case 0:
            pI = wrap(new (ibuf) A);
            break;
        default:
        case 1:
            pI = wrap(new (ibuf) B);
            break;
    }
}

IC::IC(const IC& ic)
{
    pI = ic.pI; // Keep reference on same object, don't copy or destruct anything
}

IC::IC(I&& i)
{
    if (B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(&i))
    {
        pI = wrap(new (ibuf) B(*b));
    }
    else
    {
        if (A* a = dynamic_cast<A*>(&i))
        {
            pI = wrap(new (ibuf) A(*a));
        }
    }
}

class T
{
public:
    IC GetA()
    {
        return B();
    }

};


int main()
{
    cout << "main() ->\n";
    T t;
    {
        cout << "- GetA()\n";
        IC i = t.GetA();
        i->print();
        
        cout << "- clone object\n";
        IC i2 = i;
        i2->print();

        cout << "- before scope end\n";
    }
    cout << "- main scope\n";
    cout << "<- main()\n";
}
```

And it's output:

```
main() ->
- GetA()
I ctor
B ctor
I ctor
B copy ctor
~B()
~I()
B::print()
- clone object
B::print()
- before scope end
~B()
~I()
- main scope
<- main()
```

Please note that similar concept exists in [polymorphic_value-git](https://github.com/jbcoe/polymorphic_value) - but will require separate header use.

Comment: This looks like you are reinventing `std::variant<A,B>`

Comment: @MichaelKarcher can you add example of std::variant<A,B> as answer ? Based on this article https://www.cppstories.com/2020/04/variant-virtual-polymorphism.html/ - it's not that straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

If the set of implementations of an interface is known (as required in https://stackoverflow.com/a/75946069 ), you can delegate the heavy lifting to `std::variant`. Here is a version of that code using `std::variant` as backing store:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <variant>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

class B;

class I
{
public:
    virtual ~I()
    {
        cout << "~I()\n";
    }

    I()
    {
        cout << "I ctor\n";
    }

    virtual void print() = 0;

private:
    I(const I& clone) = delete;
};

class A : public I
{
public:
    A()
    {
        cout << "A ctor\n";
    }

    ~A() override
    {
        cout << "~A()\n";
    }

    A(const A& clone)
    {
        cout << "A copy ctor\n";
    }

    void print() override
    {
        cout << "A::print()\n";
    }
};

class B : public I
{
public:
    B()
    {
        cout << "B ctor\n";
    }

    B(const B& clone)
    {
        cout << "B copy ctor\n";
    }
    
    B(B&& clone)
    {
        cout << "B move ctor\n";
    }
    
    ~B() override
    {
        cout << "~B()\n";
    }

    void print() override
    {
        cout << "B::print()\n";
    }

};

class IC    //interface container
{
    typedef std::variant<A,B> impl_t;
    impl_t impl;
public:
    // create new instance
    IC(int i);
    // copy existing instance
    IC(const impl_t& existing) : impl(existing) {}
    // move existing instance
    IC(impl_t && existing) : impl(std::move(existing)) {}

    I* operator->()
    {
        return std::visit([](auto & impl_) {return static_cast<I*>(&impl_);}, impl);
    }
};


IC::IC(int i) : impl(i == 0 ? impl_t(std::in_place_type_t<A>()) : 
                              impl_t(std::in_place_type_t<B>()))
{
}

class T
{
public:
    IC GetA1()
    {
        return IC(1);
    }

    IC GetA2()
    {
        return IC(B());
    }

};


int main()
{
    cout << "main() ->\n";
    T t;
    {
        cout << "- GetA1()\n";
        IC i = t.GetA1();
        i->print();
        
        cout << "- clone object\n";
        IC i2 = i;
        i2->print();

        cout << "- GetA2()\n";
        IC i3 = t.GetA2();
        i3->print();
        
        cout << "- before scope end\n";
    }
    cout << "- main scope\n";
    cout << "<- main()\n";
}
```

Comment: Wow. Nice ! Operation `->` looks bit ugly, but probably working solution.

Is there any article on `in_place_type_t` ?

Comment: @TarmoPikaro `std::inplace_t` is a struct template that exists to be a constructor parameter to things like `std::variant`, see overloads 5 and 6 [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant)